# How to add an extra namespace to SOAP envelope (gSOAP)

Tags: soap, gsoap, onvif

I'm implementing an ONVIF compatible device. The gSOAP toolkit is used for C++ code generation from the ONVIF WSDL files.
Everything works fine except for SOAP fault processing, ONVIF has specified an extra namespace so called ter = “http://www.onvif.org/ver10/error”. This namespace needs to be included in the SOAP envelope send by gSOAP.

I'm trying this for several days now, but i can't figure it out.

Does anybody known how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I created a fake wsdl file to solve the problem.

just take any other wsdl file, and just keep a simpletype definition of a dummy object that you are never going to use.Feed this file to gsoap and you're done.

Comment: Could you explain more please?